# Using i18n in aem publish in custom jsvascript

Tags: aem

I have a requirement like I need to have a i18n value in my custom javascript in publish instance. Could anyone please help me with it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it:

- in your js you can access object `CQ.I18n` which provides localized messages. By default it uses user locale (and not locale of current page/path).

So you can use it in next way:

```
if (CQ && CQ.I18n) {
    CQ.I18n.setLocale(_currentPathLocale_);
    var localizedMessage = CQ.I18n.getMessage(messageKey);
}
```

`_currentPathLocale_` you can inject into your js while initialization.

- another way would be to inject already localized message.

If you have next js script:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myComponent = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
             message: "Hello!"
        }

        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var localizedMessage = opts.message;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can pass from your jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#componentDiv").myComponent({message: "<fmt:message key="messageKey"/>"});
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with the first approach is that CQ object wont be available in Publish instance. and I am not using next js to use the second approach.

Comment: @Tushar Which CQ/AEM version do you use?

Comment: @Tushar probably, you do not have 'cq.shared' category included. Just include it with 'cq:includeClientLib', embed it into your global clientlib or make it a dependency of your clientlib, and CQ object will be available on publish as well.

Comment: @Tushar to get CQ object on publish instance check https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1143494?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer